# JavaScript to login account not working

Tags: javascript

Code that automatically go to login page and click login:

```
javascript: window.location = 'https://1.1.1.1/login.HTML';
while (true) {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        window.onload(document.forms[0].Submit.click());
        break;
    }
}
```

<sup>Code passed through [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/); original does not have line breaks</sup>

I paste this script on urlbar but its not working (it go to https://1.1.1.1/login.HTML but not login) 
but if I'm on https://1.1.1.1/login.HTML and paste this script it works. I don't understand why it does not work.

Comment: It might look if it comes from another page.

Comment: On which browser are you doing this? `while (true)` is effectively an infinite loop and should lock up the browser

Comment: @Yi Jiang im use firefox and remember id, pass for login

Answer (score 4):

`javascript:` URLs are run in the context of the current page.